# what's wrong with normal variable of node type?

Tags: c++, linked-list

whenever we are creating new node is it manadatory to make pointer to newnode first and allocate memory dynamically to it why can't we have normal variable of node class type !
so,what's wrong with normal variable of node type insted of having pointer to node type

CODE:

```
//creation of linked list
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class node{
    public:
    int data;
    node* next;
};
class linked_list{
    
    public:
    node* head;
    linked_list(){
        head=NULL;
    }    
    void add_node(int data);
    void display_ll();
};
void linked_list :: add_node(int data){
    node newnode;                 //HERE IN THIS LINE I KNOW IT SHOULD BE LIKE node* newnode;
    if (head==NULL){            // AND DMA THAT NODE , WORKING FINE BUT WHAT'S WRONG WITH ACTUAL CODE
        newnode.data=data;
        newnode.next=NULL;
        head=&newnode;
    }
    else{
        node* temp=head;
        newnode.data=data;
        newnode.next=NULL;
        while(temp->next!=NULL){
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp->next=&newnode;
    }

}
void linked_list :: display_ll(){
    node* temp=head;
    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
int main(){
    linked_list ll;
    ll.add_node(6);
    ll.add_node(3);
    ll.add_node(9);
    ll.add_node(3);
    ll.display_ll();

}
```

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `nullptr` and try to avoid C's typeless `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare `newnode` as `node newnode;` within your method, then the object's memory is allocated on the stack, and its life time is local to the execution context of the method: when the function returns, that memory is freed.

That becomes a problem, because after the first call (`ll.add_node(6)`), `head` will reference that freed memory. Then `ll.add_node(3)` will allocate again memory, which could well be the *same* memory on the stack, and so you'll actually overwrite the first node's data, and `temp->next=&newnode` will make a bad reference. This will happen also with the other `ll.add_node` calls. The list is thus corrupted.

When you finally call `ll.display_ll()`, its `temp` will point to freed memory and so will `temp->next`, leading to undefined behaviour, unexpected output and potentially to an exception.

So, the rule is as follows:

If your function creates a reference to the object that will remain accessible *after* the function has returned, then you must allocate that memory dynamically (using a pointer). If on the other hand the object is only relevant during the execution of the function, and can be discarded when the function returns (without any reference to it), then it is not needed to use a pointer.

Comment: This part _'you'll make a reference to this freed memory [...] and this will cause an exception.'_ is not precise enough. Yes, you _can_ get an exception – if you're lucky enough. But most probably you will _not_ get an exception when accessing that memory, because the stack area is still available to the process! However, there will be some other data at the place, so using it will lead you astray (and probably cause an exception) while writing into it will most probably destroy some other data (an cause an exception _some time later_ – or not). Anyway that is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @CiaPan, right! I have updated that paragraph.